# How can I update my Window title for macOS Storyboard Cocoa project via an action?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui

This is my project:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

var appName: String = "My App Name"

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
        self.view = controller.view
        self.view.window?.title = appName
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Change") {
                appName += " updated!"
                print(appName)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 400.0, height: 300.0)
    }
}
```

My goal is be able to update my window title, I am be able to update the variable that holds my app name but since viewWillAppear function would not be triggered I am unable to update my window title there. I was thinking to use a notification there but in this case I am not sure if it is the right feet there, because it would need to post and receive notification, what is the approach for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a ViewModel storing `title` as `@Published` and from the Button action update that property rather than a global `appName`. In your hosting controller, you can subscribe to changes of `title`, since it is `@Published` and update the window's title whenever the view model's `title` property is updated.

```
import Cocoa
import Combine
import SwiftUI

var appName: String = "My App Name"

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var title: String = appName
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

  private let viewModel = ViewModel()

  private var titleObservation: AnyCancellable?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Observe the title of the view model and update the window's title whenever it changes
    titleObservation = viewModel.$title.sink { [weak self] newTitle in
      self?.view.window?.title = newTitle
    }
  }

  override func viewWillAppear() {
    let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: ContentView(viewModel: viewModel))
    self.view = controller.view
    self.view.window?.title = viewModel.title
  }

}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ViewModel

  init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button("Change") {
        viewModel.title += " updated!"
      }
    }
    .frame(width: 400.0, height: 300.0)
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply inject a closure for the `Button` action into your view from the hosting controller and update the window's title from the closure.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

  override func viewWillAppear() {
    let contentView = ContentView(
      onButtonTap: { // this closure will be executed every time Button is tapped
        appName += " updated!"
        self.view.window?.title = appName
        print(appName)
      }
    )
    let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    self.view = controller.view
    self.view.window?.title = appName
  }

}

struct ContentView: View {
  // Closure to execute when `Button` is tapped
  private let onButtonTap: () -> Void

  init(onButtonTap: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.onButtonTap = onButtonTap
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button("Change", action: onButtonTap)
    }
    .frame(width: 400.0, height: 300.0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your good answer since I am not familiar with Combine, could you update your answer that it does not use Combine. Do not get me wrong your answer is good but i need to understand the codes.

Comment: @Milen I did explain the Combine part. I wouldn't recommend using a less modern/optimal solution just to avoid using Combine. SwiftUI and Combine work hand in hand, you cannot really avoid learning the basics of Combine if you plan on using SwiftUI, since SwiftUI is powered by several Combine features, such as `@Published` and `ObservableObject`.

Comment: Thanks so could you please add a second way to the answer, that would be great for me with my level.

Comment: @Milen I've added a solution using closures and no Combine, but I really recommend you to learn the basics of Combine, otherwise you won't be able to utilise the full features of SwiftUI

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, I know the others would appreciate your first answer and sorry for my low information about Combine.  My last question, should i just use global appName for second way or using a class like you did in first way but without being ObservableObject, because in second way there is no need to being ObservableObject or you could give your idea about this global appName. how could I do this part in right way, but if you have time to help.

Comment: @Milen you should always avoid global variables when possible. You don't necessarily need a ViewModel for the 2nd approach, you can simply declare the `String` as a variable on your `ViewController`. This is all assuming that you only need this variable for updating the title of your window and don't need it outside your view controller and its view.